# Is there a command line option to start Brave browser with Shields down by default?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, brave, brave-browser

I'm using Selenium with Python and I'm trying to access a website which is broken if the Brave Shields are up, and in particular if blocking fingerprinting. I'd like to find a way to disable Shields or just the blocking of fingerprinting via Selenium. If there is a command line option to disable Shields by default when opening Brave via command line, I could just add an option to the driver:

```py
options = ChromeOptions()

disable_shields = 'correct command line option for shields down' 
options.add_argument(disable-shields)

options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/brave-browser"

driver = Chrome(options=options)
```

I couldn't find a list of costum command line options for brave-browser, just the chromium ones.

A different approach, instead of the command line option, would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

All I could find by the moment is these links:

- brave://settings/shields (you can change directly from here the Brave Shield Settings using Selenium)
- https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044860011-How-Do-I-Use-Command-Line-Flags-in-Brave- (here you have all flags you can disable)
- https://brave.com/privacy-updates/ (here you have all anti-fingerprinting techniques Brave uses)

You can change flags with command line arguments.

I will update this in some hours when I'm able to.

Comment: I thought about the first solution, but Selenium doesn't see the setting page as a standard hmtl page and I wasn't able to make it interact with the page. I also found the website with "all" the flags, but actually the one reported are the general ones for chromium and there isn't anyone Brave specific. I think the first solution would be ok, but, as I said, I couldn't do it, if you can, please share your solution.